# Filter request with the Bolt CMS Rest API

Tags: bolt-cms

I want to fetch a record via Bolt CMS's REST API based on the record's slug. Is there a possibility to filter results?

I would expect a syntax like
`filter[slug][_eq]=<my slug>`
Or can I use the sulg to directly fetch the record?
I'm using version 5.